# Improving OCaml code involving usage of local definitions

Tags: ocaml

I am taking a MOOC course on OCaml and have had this as a homework question which involves joining a string using only 5 concat operators "^" and creating a resultant string which has 9 occurences of the original string separated by a ",".

Even though I managed to solve it by the following solution I think the code is not good enough/I am not understanding the concept of using a local definition.

```
let sentence = (let word3 = (let word2 = (let word1= word ^ "," in 
let word2 = word1 ^ word1 in word2) in 
let word3 = word2 ^word2 in word3) in
let word4 = word3 ^ word3 in word4) ^ word;;
```

Please help me understand the concept with a better solution. Kindly remember that you should only use 5 concat operators.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to point out is that this expression:

```
let a = b in a
```

is equivalent to this expression:

```
b
```

If you make this substitution in your code you get the following:

```
let sentence =
    (let word3 =
        (let word2 = 
            (let word1 = word ^ "," in word1 ^ word1)
         in 
         word2 ^ word2)
     in
     word3 ^ word3) ^ word
```

This is pretty reasonable code. It's a little hard to follow because of the nesting. You have nested `let ... in` like this:

```
let a =
    let b = 3 in
    b * b
in
a + 7
```

But you could have something more like this:

```
let b = 3 in
let a = b * b in
a + 7
```

If you make this change to your code you get this:

```
let word1 = word ^ "," in
let word2 = word1 ^ word1 in
let word3 = word2 ^ word2 in
let sentence = word3 ^ word3 ^ word
```

**Update**

Note that this is equivalent to your code, but isn't a full expression. If you want to test it out, add this to the end:

```
in sentence
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Thanks for replying. I was try this code at https://try.ocamlpro.com/ when I tried your code I am getting a Syntax error: File "", line 4, characters 35-37: Error: Syntax error.

Comment: You code doesn't do anything with `sentence` after defining it. I assume it's part of a larger expression. To evaluate the code you can add `in sentence` to the end.